# how to use window.location.search

Tags: dart, dart-html

How to use `window.location.search` to print url parameters from the dart program 
I am not able to understand how to use `Uri`.

```dart
import 'dart:core';
import 'dart:html';

void main(){
 Uri u = new Uri();
 u = 'http://mydomain.com/path/Sandbox.html?paramA=1&parmB=2'; 
 print(window.location.search);
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain **why** you do this and what you actually try to accomplish?

Comment: I want to exctract `?paramA=1&parmB=2` from url i.e extract url parameters and store them in dart session variable

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by Dart session variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create an Uri like

```dart
Uri u = Uri.parse('http://mydomain.com/path/Sandbox.html?paramA=1&parmB=2');
print(u.query);
```

I don't know what kind of session variable your are using therefor I haven't added something about this.

Comment: and how is window.location.search is used

Comment: I have never used `window.location.search` myself yet, but what I found is that it returns the query part of the URL of the browsers current value in the URL field.
I guess it will give you the same value as `Uri.parse(window.location).query` 
see http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_search.asp